Snowflake SQL to Create Roles and SQL Statements. , facing unexpected <EOF> or unexpected 'END'
We intend to dynamically create roles based on SF metadata. Preferably through a Stored Procedure.
However, we are struggling to debug and spend way too much time investigating error codes that SF returns.
The idea of below is to simply Return "CREATE ROLE IF NOT EXISTS" Statements of all schemas that exist in our DB. Role names are based on the prefix "PROD_DB_R_S_" with the respective schema name in question.
Execute IMMEDIATE $$
DECLARE
schemanamex VARCHAR;
rolename VARCHAR;


BEGIN
 
FOR  schemarec IN (SELECT SCHEMA_NAME FROM PROD_DB.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA) DO
   schemanamex := schemarec.SCHEMA_NAME;
 
   rolename := "PROD_DB_R_S_"|| schemanamex;
 
   RETURN "CREATE ROLE IF NOT EXISTS "||rolename||";";
END;
$$
;

--> syntax error line 16 at position 0 unexpected EOF

You don't have an END FOR

As seen in the comments, you need an end for. Also you need a cursor. Both added in this working solution:
Execute IMMEDIATE $$
DECLARE
schemanamex VARCHAR;
rolename VARCHAR;


BEGIN
    LET c1 CURSOR FOR (SELECT SCHEMA_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA);
    FOR  schemarec IN c1 DO
       return schemarec.SCHEMA_NAME;    
       --rolename := "PROD_DB_R_S_"|| schemanamex;   
       --RETURN "CREATE ROLE IF NOT EXISTS "||rolename||";";
    END FOR;
END;
$$
;

